# Perl, Any match string after a pattern

Tags: regex, string, perl, matching, any

I'm trying to match if any string exists after a certain pattern.
The pattern is "pattern" 'anything in between' "[after]". case insensitive.

e.g

```
pattern 1 [after] ABC
pattern 2 [after] 123 abc DEX
pattern 3 [after] 
pattern 12345123 [after]
pattern @ASd#98 @_90sd [after] xyz dec
[after] 4 pattern
```

So the result I would like to obtain is,

```
pattern 1 [after] ABC
pattern 2 [after] 123 abc DEX
pattern @ASd#98 @_90sd [after] xyz dec
```

It begins with "pattern" and ends with "[after],  anything sandwiched between is also accepted.

I'm having difficulty incorporating the delimits of [ ] & if string exists together.

I've tried, the closest I've gotten ends up matching

```
m/pattern/ ../ \[after]/

pattern 1 [after] ABC
pattern 2 [after] 123 ABC DEX
pattern 3 [after] 
pattern 12345123 [after]
pattern @ASd#98 @_90sd [after] xyz dec
```

But I don't need the 3rd or 4th pattern as it doesn't hold any numerics or characters after "[after]".

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't make any sense of your question. Even the regular expression you show contains multiple slashes and wouldn't compile, and it is unclear whether you are showing literal data or some sort of pseudo-language. Please show real data and examples of what you need to match or reject

Comment: I'm not sure how come the regex didn't compile for you, it compiles and runes for me. The multiple slashes with ".." is a perl regular expression to include everything in between two patterns. Whatever is unclear please tell me, I'll try to make more sense of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code I used to test against your input (which I just cat'ed and piped to the script)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while(<>)
{
    print if (/^pattern.*\[after\]\s*\S+/);
}
```

So to break it down for you:

`/^pattern` : match any string that begins with "pattern"

`.*\[after\]` : match any characters followed by "[after]"

`\s*\S+` : match 0 or more whitespace characters followed by one or more non-whitespace character

That should give you enough to work with to tweak it up as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
$str = 'pattern 2 [after] 123 abc DEX';

if ($str =~ m/^pattern\s+(\d+)\s+\[after\]\s+(.+)/) {
  print "$1\t$2\n";
} else {
  print "(no match)\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2   123 abc DEX
```

Test this code [here](http://ideone.com/sp1wt).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
/pattern [0-9] \[after\](?= .)/s
```

or

```
/pattern [0-9] \[after\] ./s
```